# why is my dash application not running as expected?

Tags: callback, visualization, plotly-dash

i am quite new to data visualization using plotly and dash. I am trying to complete this exercise but cant seem to find whats wrong with the code. The application is meant to receive two inputs of dropdown options where one is disabled based on the selection of the other.

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px

# Load the data using pandas
data = pd.read_csv('https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DV0101EN-SkillsNetwork/Data%20Files/historical_automobile_sales.csv')

# Initialize the Dash app
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# Set the title of the dashboard
app.title = "Automobile Statistics Dashboard"

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create the dropdown menu options
dropdown_options = [
    {'label': 'Yearly Statistics', 'value': 'Yearly Statistics'},
    {'label': 'Recession Period Statistics', 'value': 'Recession Period Statistics'}
]
# List of years 
year_list = [i for i in range(1980, 2024, 1)]
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create the layout of the app
app.layout = html.Div([
    #TASK 2.1 Add title to the dashboard
    html.H1("Automobile Sales Statistics Dashboard", style={'textAlign': 'center', 'color': '#503D36',
                                'font-size': 24}),#May include style for title
    html.Div([#TASK 2.2: Add two dropdown menus
        html.Label("Select Statistics:"),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown-statistics',
            options=[{'label': 'Yearly Statistics', 'value': 'Yearly Statistics'},
            {'label':'Recession Period Statistics', 'value': 'Recession Period Statistics'}],
            placeholder='Select a report type',
            style={'width': '80%', 'padding':'3px', 'font-size':'20px', 'text-align-last':'center'}
        )
    ]),
    html.Div(dcc.Dropdown(
            id='select-year',
            options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in year_list],
            placeholder='Select a year type',
            style={'width': '80%', 'padding':'3px', 'font-size':'20px', 'text-align-last':'center'}
        )),
    html.Div([#TASK 2.3: Add a division for output display
    html.Div(id='output_container', className='chart-grid', style={'display':'flex'}),])
])
#TASK 2.4: Creating Callbacks
# Define the callback function to update the input container based on the selected statistics
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='select-year', component_property='disabled'),
    Input(component_id='dropdown-statistics', component_property='value'))

def update_input_container(dropdown_options):
    if dropdown_options =='Yearly Statistics': 
        return False
    else: 
        return True

#Callback for plotting
# Define the callback function to update the input container based on the selected statistics
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output_container', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='select-year', component_property='value'), Input(component_id='dropdown-statistics', component_property='value')])


def update_output_container(dropdown_options, input_year):
    if dropdown_options == 'Recession Period Statistics':
        # Filter the data for recession periods
        recession_data = data[data['Recession'] == 1]
        
#TASK 2.5: Creating Graphs for Recession data

#Plot 1 Automobile sales fluctuate over Recession Period (year wise)
        # use groupby to create relevant data for plotting
        yearly_rec=recession_data.groupby('Year')['Automobile_Sales'].mean().reset_index()
        R_chart1 = dcc.Graph(
            figure=px.line(yearly_rec, 
                x='Year',
                y='Automobile_Sales',
                title="Average Automobile Sales fluctuation over Recession Period"))

#Plot 2 Calculate the average number of vehicles sold by vehicle type       
        # use groupby to create relevant data for plotting
        average_sales = recession_data.groupby(['Vehicle_Type'])['Automobile_Sales'].mean().reset_index()                           
        R_chart2  = dcc.Graph(figure=px.line(average_sales, x='Vehicle_Type', y='Automobile_Sales', title='Average Number of Vehicles Sold by Vehicle Type'))
        
# Plot 3 Pie chart for total expenditure share by vehicle type during recessions
        # use groupby to create relevant data for plotting
        exp_rec= recession_data.groupby(['Vehicle_Type'])['Advertising_Expenditure'].sum().reset_index
        R_chart3 = dcc.Graph(figure=px.pie(exp_rec, values='pop', names='Vehicle_Type', title='Total Expenditure Share by Vehicle Type during Recessions'))

# Plot 4 bar chart for the effect of unemployment rate on vehicle type and sales
        recession_data = data[data['Recession'==1]]
        R_chart4 = dcc.Graph(figure=px.histogram(recession_data), x='unemployment_rate', hue='Vehicle_Type', title='Effect of Unemployment Rate on Vehicle Type and Sales')

#TASK 2.6: Returning the graphs for displaying Recession data
        return [
            html.Div(className='chart-grid', children=[html.Div(children=R_chart1),html.Div(children=R_chart2)],style={'display': 'flex'}),
            html.Div(className='chart-grid', children=[html.Div(children=R_chart3),html.Div(children=R_chart4)],style={'display': 'flex'})
            ]
 # Yearly Statistic Report Plots                             
    elif (dropdown_options== 'Yearly Statistics') :
        yearly_data = data[data['Year'] == input_year]
                              
#TASK 2.5: Creating Graphs Yearly data
                              
#plot 1 Yearly Automobile sales using line chart for the whole period.
        yas= data.groupby('Year')['Automobile_Sales'].mean().reset_index()
        Y_chart1 = dcc.Graph(figure=px.line(yas, 
                x='Year',
                y='Automobile_Sales',
                title="Average Automobile Sales fluctuation over Time"))
            
# Plot 2 Total Monthly Automobile sales using line chart.
        Y_chart2 = dcc.Graph(data, x='Month', y='Automobile_Sales', title='Total Monthly Automobile Sales')

            # Plot bar chart for average number of vehicles sold during the given year
        avr_vdata=yearly_data.groupby(['Vehicle_Type'])['Automobile_Sales'].mean().reset_index
        Y_chart3 = dcc.Graph( figure=px.bar(avr_vdata, x='Vehicle_Type', y='Automobile_Sales', hue='Vehicle_Type', title='Average Vehicles Sold by Vehicle Type in the year {}'.format(input_year)))

            # Total Advertisement Expenditure for each vehicle using pie chart
        exp_data=yearly_data.groupby(['Vehicle_Type'])['Advertising_Expenditure'].sum().reset_index
        Y_chart4 = dcc.Graph(figure=px.pie(exp_data, values='pop', names='Vehicle_Type', title='Total Expenditure Share by Vehicle Type'))

#TASK 2.6: Returning the graphs for displaying Yearly data
        return [
                html.Div(className='chart-grid', children=[html.Div(children=Y_chart1),html.Div(children=Y_chart2)],style={'display': 'flex'}),
                html.Div(className='chart-grid', children=[html.Div(children=Y_chart3),html.Div(children=Y_chart4)],style={'display': 'flex'})
                ]
        
    else:
        return None

# Run the Dash app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I followed all the task completion prompt but i am not getting the output container after selecting the dropdown options and there isnt any error message.

Answer (score 0):

Done that, there you go:

```
# Initialize the Dash app
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# Set the title of the dashboard
# app.title = "Automobile Statistics Dashboard"

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create the dropdown menu options

dropdown_options = [
    {'label': 'Yearly Statistics', 'value': 'Yearly Statistics'},
    {'label': 'Recession Period Statistics', 'value': 'Recession Period Statistics'}
]
# List of years 
year_list = [i for i in range(1980, 2024, 1)]
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create the layout of the app
app.layout = html.Div([
    #TASK 2.1 Add title to the dashboard
    html.H1("Automobile Sales Statistics Dashboard",style={'textAlign': 'center', 'color': '#503D36',
                                'font-size': 24}),
    html.Div([#TASK 2.2: Add two dropdown menus
        html.Label("Select Statistics:"),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown-statistics',
            options=dropdown_options,
            value='Select Statistics',
            placeholder='Select a report type'
        )
    ]),
    html.Div(dcc.Dropdown(
            id='select-year',
            options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in year_list],
            placeholder= 'Select Year'
        )),
    html.Div([#TASK 2.3: Add a division for output display
    html.Div(id='output-container', className='chart-grid', style={'display': 'flex'}),])
])
#TASK 2.4: Creating Callbacks
# Define the callback function to update the input container based on the selected statistics
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='select-year', component_property='disabled'),
    Input(component_id='dropdown-statistics',component_property='value'))

def update_input_container(selected_statistics):
    if selected_statistics =='Yearly Statistics': 
        return False
    else: 
        return True

#Callback for plotting
# Define the callback function to update the input container based on the selected statistics
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output-container', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='dropdown-statistics', component_property='value'), Input(component_id='select-year', component_property='value')])

def update_output_container(selected_statistics,input_year):
    if selected_statistics == 'Recession Period Statistics':
        print("Recession")
        # Filter the data for recession periods
        recession_data = data[data['Recession'] == 1]
        print(recession_data.head())

#TASK 2.5: Create and display graphs for Recession Report Statistics

#Plot 1 Automobile sales fluctuate over Recession Period (year wise)
        # use groupby to create relevant data for plotting
        yearly_rec=recession_data.groupby('Year')['Automobile_Sales'].mean().reset_index()
        R_chart1 = dcc.Graph(
                figure=px.line(yearly_rec, 
                x='Year',
                y='Automobile_Sales',
                title="Average Automobile Sales fluctuation over Recession Period"))

#Plot 2 Calculate the average number of vehicles sold by vehicle type       
        # use groupby to create relevant data for plotting
        average_sales = recession_data.groupby('Vehicle_Type')['Automobile_Sales'].mean().reset_index()                           
        R_chart2  = dcc.Graph(
                figure=px.bar(average_sales, 
                x='Vehicle_Type',
                y='Automobile_Sales',
                title="Average Automobile Sales per Vehicle Type over Recession Period"))

# Plot 3 Pie chart for total expenditure share by vehicle type during recessions
        # use groupby to create relevant data for plotting
        exp_rec= recession_data.groupby('Vehicle_Type')['Advertising_Expenditure'].sum().reset_index()
        R_chart3 = dcc.Graph(
                 figure=px.pie(exp_rec,
                 values='Advertising_Expenditure',
                 names='Vehicle_Type',
                 title="Advertising Expenditure per Vehicle Type over Recession Period"
                )
        )
# Plot 4 bar chart for the effect of unemployment rate on vehicle type and sales
        average_sales = recession_data.groupby(['unemployment_rate','Vehicle_Type'])['Automobile_Sales'].mean().reset_index()                           
        R_chart4  = dcc.Graph(
                figure=px.bar(average_sales, 
                x='unemployment_rate',
                y='Automobile_Sales',
                color = 'Vehicle_Type',
                title="The effect of unemployment rate on vehicle type and sales over Recession Period"))


        return [
            html.Div(className='chart-item', children=[html.Div(children=R_chart1),html.Div(children=R_chart2)],style={'display': 'flex'}),
            html.Div(className='chart-item', children=[html.Div(children=R_chart3),html.Div(children=R_chart4)],style={'display': 'flex'})
            ]

# TASK 2.6: Create and display graphs for Yearly Report Statistics
 # Yearly Statistic Report Plots                             
    elif (selected_statistics=='Yearly Statistics') :
        print("Year")
        yearly_data = data[data['Year'] == input_year]
                              
#TASK 2.5: Creating Graphs Yearly data
                              
#plot 1 Yearly Automobile sales using line chart for the whole period.
        yas= data.groupby('Year')['Automobile_Sales'].mean().reset_index()
        Y_chart1 = dcc.Graph(
                figure=px.line(yas,
                x='Year',
                y='Automobile_Sales',
                title="Average automobile sales over time"))
            
# Plot 2 Total Monthly Automobile sales using line chart.
        mas = yearly_data.groupby('Month')['Automobile_Sales'].sum().reset_index()
        Y_chart2 = dcc.Graph(
                figure=px.line(mas,
                x='Month',
                y='Automobile_Sales',
                title="Total automobile sales per month in the year {}".format(input_year)))
                
            # Plot bar chart for average number of vehicles sold during the given year
        avr_vdata=yearly_data.groupby('Vehicle_Type')['Automobile_Sales'].mean().reset_index()
        Y_chart3 = dcc.Graph(
                figure=px.bar(avr_vdata,
                x='Vehicle_Type',
                y='Automobile_Sales',
                title='Average Vehicles Sold by Vehicle Type in the year {}'.format(input_year)))

            # Total Advertisement Expenditure for each vehicle using pie chart
        exp_data=yearly_data.groupby('Vehicle_Type')['Advertising_Expenditure'].sum().reset_index()
        Y_chart4 = dcc.Graph(
                figure=px.pie(exp_data,
                values='Advertising_Expenditure',
                names='Vehicle_Type',
                title='Advertising Expenditure per Vehicle Type in the year {}'.format(input_year)))

#TASK 2.6: Returning the graphs for displaying Yearly data
        return [
                html.Div(className='chart-item', children=[html.Div(children=Y_chart1),html.Div(children=Y_chart2)],style={'display': 'flex'}),
                html.Div(className='chart-item', children=[html.Div(children=Y_chart3),html.Div(children=Y_chart4)],style={'display': 'flex'})

                ]
        
    else:
        print("None")
        return None

# Run the Dash app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).